# Will my software work on the next version of Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have some software and I'd like to know if it works on the next version of Windows (Windows 10).

Comment: I am attempting to create a self Q and A as there have been a few "will software X work when upgrading". I'm also hoping this post will be vague enough that we could eventually remove the Windows 10 flag and have it generic (but that obviously depends on what the next OS brings). Feel free to edit my post or answer, or post your own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Windows 10 you have 30 days where you can roll back. So you could upgrade and then test it, if it fails, roll it back.

You also have the option of virtual machines.

I don't recommend asking others if they have had success because their computer spec/environment is likely to be different which may cause different behaviours.

As per @BigChris comments

> You've also got the "compatibility mode" options that attempt to help older software continue to run on newer OSes... ideally, though, the OP should be finding out from the software vendor if they have a new version for Windows 10...

Comment: You've also got the "compatibility mode" options that attempt to help older software continue to run on newer OSes... ideally, though, the OP should be finding out from the software vendor if they have a new version for Windows 10...

Comment: You could also try [modern.ie](http://modern.ie) which is provided by Microsoft and last for about 60 days.